# Show that the geodesics in normal coordinates have unit speed

Tags: differential-geometry

Given the normal coordinate system $y^ \alpha$, show that the geodesics are radial lines of the form $tv$, where $v$ is a vector of length 1.

I have managed to show that the geodesics are radial lines and that $g_{\alpha\beta}(0)=\delta_{\alpha\beta}$.  I don't know how to verify that the norm of $v$ is necessarily 1.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v$ doesn't need to be unit length, but you can choose it to be unit length, and you describe the same geodesic.

Comment: Riiiiight, because any solution to the geodesic equation multiplied by a scalar is also a solution.  Derp.